# JavaFx not populating the entry

Tags: java, javafx

This is my JavaFX code and I am trying to create a to-do list. When I try to populate my Task tab, it is not accepting the entry. The rest of the tab is accepting the entries.

I believe it has to do with the setter and getter methods. I tried using the lambda expression instead of the PropertyValue() but could not find the solutions.

The text field is supposed to accept the entry when the user enters any input.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
// import java.io.FileInputStream;
// import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
// import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
// import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;


/**
 *
 * @author Bahr
 */
public class App extends Application {
    
    private final TableView<Task> tableChron = new TableView<Task>();
    private final ObservableList<Task> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Task("Wash car", "Saturday", "8:00am", "Monthly", "Dad", "Squeaky clean"),
        new Task("Java project", "Mon & Wed", "6:00am", "Apr 23", "Professor Lambda", "Use JavaFX, git & command line"));
        
    final HBox hb = new HBox();
    Label response;
    
    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        //To create: Add check box next to each task you add, delete and edit buttons, add a week and month view, and a menu on top so you can save different copies. 
                
        VBox vBox1 = new VBox(); // Create new vertical box.
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(vBox1); // Create scene1.
        vBox1.setSpacing(7); // Spacing for box.
    
        response = new Label("Menu");
        
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("_File"); // Alt-f shortcut for file 
        MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open...");
        MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save As...");
        MenuItem print = new MenuItem("Print...");
        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        SeparatorMenuItem separator = new SeparatorMenuItem();
               
        fileMenu.getItems().add(open);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(save);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(print);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(separator);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(exit);
                        
        menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);
        
        // Create one event handler that will handle menu action events.
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> MEHandler = 
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
                String name = ((MenuItem)ae.getTarget()).getText();
 
                // if Exit is chosen, the program is  terminated.
                if(name.equals("Exit")) Platform.exit();
 
                response.setText( name + " selected");
            }
        };
        
        open.setOnAction(MEHandler);
        save.setOnAction(MEHandler);
        print.setOnAction(MEHandler);
        exit.setOnAction(MEHandler);
        
        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                        
        open.setOnAction(
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                        File opensFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                        if (opensFile != null) {
                            openFile(opensFile);
                        }
                    }
                
                });
        
        save.setOnAction(
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        File savesFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
                        if (savesFile != null) {
                            saveFile(savesFile);
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
        
        // Allow a clicks on the print menuItem to open the print dialogue box.
        print.setOnAction(
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
                        if (job != null) {
                            boolean showPrintDialog = job.showPrintDialog(primaryStage.getOwner());
                            if(showPrintDialog){
                                job.endJob();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                                      
        final Label label = new Label("To Do List"); // Main window heading label.
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 18));
        label.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        tableChron.setEditable(true);
        
        // Column headings in the tableChron.
        TableColumn<Task,String> taskCol = new TableColumn<>("Task");
        TableColumn<Task,String> dayCol = new TableColumn<>("Day");
        TableColumn<Task,String> timeCol = new TableColumn<>("Time");
        TableColumn<Task,String> deadlineCol = new TableColumn<>("Deadline");
        TableColumn<Task,String> mentorCol = new TableColumn<>("Mentor");
        TableColumn<Task,String> descriptionCol = new TableColumn<>("Task Description");
                
        taskCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Task"));
        taskCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        taskCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setToDo(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        dayCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Day"));
        dayCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        dayCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setDay(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        timeCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Time"));
        timeCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        timeCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTime(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        deadlineCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Deadline"));
        deadlineCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        deadlineCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setDeadline(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        mentorCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Mentor"));
        mentorCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        mentorCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setMentor(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        descriptionCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("Description"));
        descriptionCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        descriptionCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> t) {
                    ((Task) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setDescription(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        
        tableChron.setItems(data);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(taskCol);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(dayCol);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(timeCol);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(deadlineCol);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(mentorCol);
        tableChron.getColumns().add(descriptionCol);


        // tableChron.getColumns().addAll(taskCol, dayCol, timeCol, deadlineCol, mentorCol, descriptionCol); // Place the column headings in tableChron.
    // Set width
    tableChron.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    taskCol.setMinWidth(150);
    dayCol.setMinWidth(70);
    timeCol.setMinWidth(60);
    deadlineCol.setMinWidth(60);
    mentorCol.setMinWidth(120);
    descriptionCol.setMinWidth(200);

    // Create horizontal box.
    HBox hbox1 = new HBox();
    hbox1.setSpacing(8);
        hbox1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        // Create text fields so the user can enter new tasks into the table.
    TextField tftask = new TextField();
    TextField tfDay = new TextField();
    TextField tfTime = new TextField();
    TextField tfDeadline = new TextField();
    TextField tfmentor = new TextField();
    TextField tfdesc = new TextField();
        
        // Set initial text in fields.
    tftask.setText("Enter task");
    tfDay.setText("Enter day");
    tfTime.setText("Time");
    tfDeadline.setText("Deadline");
    tfmentor.setText("Give report to...");
    tfdesc.setText("Add specific descriptions");

        // Set length
        tftask.setPrefWidth(150);
        tfDay.setPrefWidth(75);
        tfTime.setPrefWidth(65);
        tfDeadline.setPrefWidth(65);
        tfmentor.setPrefWidth(120);
        tfdesc.setPrefWidth(150);
        
    // Create add button. 
    Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
    btnAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                data.add(new Task(
                    tftask.getText(),
                    tfDay.getText(),
                    tfTime.getText(),
                    tfDeadline.getText(),
                    tfmentor.getText(),
                    tfdesc.getText()));
                    tftask.clear();
                    tfDay.clear();
                    tfTime.clear();
                    tfDeadline.clear();
                    tfmentor.clear();
                    tfdesc.clear();
            }
        });
        
        // Get user entry fields all in a horizontal row.
    hbox1.getChildren().addAll(tftask, tfDay, tfTime, tfDeadline, tfmentor, tfdesc, btnAdd);
        
    // Get all items in a vertical, stacking format.
    vBox1.getChildren().addAll(menuBar, label, tableChron, hbox1);

    primaryStage.setWidth(750);
    primaryStage.setHeight(500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Task Tracker 1.0"); // Names the window.
    primaryStage.setScene (scene1); // Sets the scene to the stage.
    primaryStage.show(); // Shows the stage.
    }
    
    public static class Task {
        
        private final SimpleStringProperty todo;
        private final SimpleStringProperty day;
        private final SimpleStringProperty time;
        private final SimpleStringProperty deadline;
        private final SimpleStringProperty mentor;
        private final SimpleStringProperty description;
               
        private Task(String todo1, String day1, String time1, String deadline1, String mentor1, String description1){
            
            this.todo = new SimpleStringProperty(todo1);
            this.day = new SimpleStringProperty (day1);
            this.time = new SimpleStringProperty(time1);
            this.deadline = new SimpleStringProperty(deadline1);
            this.mentor = new SimpleStringProperty(mentor1);
            this.description = new SimpleStringProperty(description1);
        }
        
        public String getToDo() {
            return todo.get();
        }
        
        public void setToDo(String todo1) {
            todo.set(todo1);
        }
        
        public String getDay() {
            return day.get();
        }
        
        public void setDay(String day1) {
            day.set(day1);
        }
        
        public String getTime() {
            return time.get();
        }
        
        public void setTime(String time1) {
            time.set(time1);
        }
        
        public String getDeadline() {
            return deadline.get();
        }
        
        public void setDeadline(String deadline1) {
            deadline.set(deadline1);
        }
        
        public String getMentor() {
            return mentor.get();
        }
        
        public void setMentor(String mentor1) {
            mentor.set(mentor1);
        }
        
        public String getDescription() {
            return description.get();
        }
        
        public void setDescription(String deadline1) {
            description.set(deadline1);
        }
                
    }
    
    private void openFile(File opensFile) {
        try{
            desktop.open(opensFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                    App.class.getName()).log(
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                    );
        }
    }
    
    private void saveFile(File savesFile) {
        try{
            desktop.open(savesFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                    App.class.getName()).log(
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                    );
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="VBox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="819.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="App">
   <children>
      <MenuBar fx:id="MenuBar">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="Menu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File" />
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <Label prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="133.0" text="TO DO LIST">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TableView fx:id="tableview" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="712.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="taskCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="TASK" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="dayCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="DAY" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="timeCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="TIME" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="deadlineCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="DEADLINE" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="mentorCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="MENTOR" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="descriptionCol" prefWidth="125.0" text="TASK DESCRIPTION" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <HBox fx:id="Hbox" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tftask" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="111.0" promptText="Enter Task" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfday" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="118.0" promptText="Enter Day" />
            <TextField fx:id="tftime" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="96.0" promptText="Time" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfdeadline" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="98.0" promptText="Deadline" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfmentor" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="123.0" promptText="Give report to" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfdesc" promptText="Add specific description" />
            <Button fx:id="btnAdd" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonADD" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="ADD" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: the Task class has no property named "Task" .. anyway: __understand__  how to use tableView, all factories are given the wrong parameter (though the implementation is lenient in this case ;), do not use propertyValueFactory. When asking for debugging help, always provide a [mcve] minding the __M__!

Comment: `java.awt.Desktop` is not the right thing to use to open and save your todo list files.

Comment: Perhaps study the [makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/), that might help you with your application.  Not this specific question which is already answered in the duplicate, but just as an approach in general.